# Returning response in AFNETWORKING

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course) tutorial to learn AfNetworking in IOS 
And I am using the following function to get the response from the server:

```
{
    // 1
    NSString *weatherUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // 2
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        // 3
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            //Success
        }
        // 4
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [av show];
        }];

    // 5
    [operation start];
}
```

What I want is to write a function which will returns the response as a `NSString` after getting response. I don't know the syntax.Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Since your example is Async, the method will return before the response is recieved. Just call a method in the success block (where the comment `//Success` is written and pass the received JSON to that method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Try this


- (void)getResponse:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))block {
       NSString *weatherUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherUrl];
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

      // 2
      AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
       [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
      // 3
      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //Success
                   block(JSON,nil); //call block here
      }
     // 4
     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)    {
          UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving     Weather"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [av show];
      }];

  // 5
  [operation start];

}
```

calling

```
[self getResponse:^(id result, NSError *error) {
         //use result here
 }];
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Whe I tried to complile your cod I am getting the error in block(JSON,nil);  " Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to '__autoreleasing id *' is disallowed with ARC"

Comment: Hey I just remove * in *result.Then it Worked.Thank you so much

Comment: oops edited remove the * before result in parameter it will work

Answer (score 0):

You could simply log it like this where //success is

```
NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
```

Or if you wanted it in a string format then:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON response is %@", JSON];
```

Hope this helps.